# MYSQL returning strange results with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to do a forum system optimization which selects all the last posters in one query and stored them in an array. Thing is the database is returning un-expected results

PHP version 5.3.13

MySQL version   5.1.63

```
$getPosts = $dB->fetch('
  SELECT
    post_id, post_poster_id, post_topic_id, post_time,
    COUNT(post_id) as count
  FROM forum_posts
  WHERE post_topic_id IN (
    SELECT topic_id
    FROM forum_topics
    WHERE topic_forum_id = ' . $forum_id . '
  )
  GROUP BY post_topic_id
  ORDER BY post_time DESC
');
foreach($getPosts as $lastPoster)
{
    $lastPosts[$lastPoster['post_topic_id']] = $lastPoster;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output.

Comment: please elaborate more. What did you mean by unexpected result? Group by will group the rows by `post_topic_id`

Comment: You are trying to fetch multiple rows of data with COUNT function in the query which could give unexpected results.

Comment: `ORDER BY AVG(post_time) DESC`, `ORDER BY MIN(post_time) DESC`, or `ORDER BY MAX(post_time) DESC`?

Comment: ... and you might want to learn about `JOIN`'s instead of subqueries.

Comment: @user1486625 Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure that you include all relevant information in your question, `the database is returning un-expected results` doesn't really help us answer the question as you don't tell us what you are getting, why this is unexpected and what you were expecting instead. Please add some more information to your question, and please check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as soon as you can, so you know what we expect from you and what you can expect from us. For SQL problems providing an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is always helpful, too.

Comment: A partial GROUP BY can often produce "unexpected" results. For example the columns that are not specified in `GROUP BY` clause do not sort the way you "expect".

Comment: Ok sorry, what I expect is a list of forum_posts from each forum_topic that was most recent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   p.post_id, p.post_poster_id, p.post_topic_id, p.post_time, l.count

FROM forum_posts AS p

-- joining with list of latests in a derived table
INNER JOIN

-- getting latest time and count
(SELECT p.post_topic_id, MAX(post_time) AS post_time, COUNT(post_id) AS count
FROM forum_posts AS p
-- filtering forum_id with join, join is usually preferrable than subquery
INNER JOIN forum_topics AS t ON t.topic_id = p.post_topic_id AND t.topic_forum_id = '$forum_id'
GROUP BY post_topic_id)

AS l USING(post_topic_id, post_time)

-- grouping to strip possible post_time-in-one-topic-duplicates
GROUP BY p.post_topic_id
```